# What I need to put "url" in mapbox addSource

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

This is my first time using mapbox and I can't figure out how to addSource when map load.

Below is the [sample code](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures-around-point/).

I uploaded 'KML' file for tilesets and I want to use this tileset for source, but I don't know how to write 'url' part.

I also want to know what is 'source-layer'. What should I write in the 'source-layer?

I am sorry I know this is very basic question, but I really need to know.
Please help me.
Thanks.

```
map.on('load', function() {
// Add the source to query. In this example we're using
// county polygons uploaded as vector tiles
map.addSource('counties', {
"type": "vector",
"url": "mapbox://mapbox.82pkq93d"  <<---here
});

map.addLayer({
"id": "counties",
"type": "fill",
"source": "counties",
"source-layer": "original",  <<---source layer
"paint": {
"fill-outline-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
"fill-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
}
}, 'place-city-sm'); // Place polygon under these labels.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Your tile url should also be fine like this:

```
mapbox://{}
```

It is a bit tricky to find in the documentation: When uploading KML you are creating **tileset** for which you should get a **map ID**. With the map ID you can either request separate tiles using a [tile url](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-tiles) like this:

`/v4/{map_id}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}{@2x}.{format}`

You can use the tile url when adding a source

```
map.addSource({
  type: 'vector',
  tiles: ['https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{map_id}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.mvt']
});
```

Or you can request a [TileJSON metadata object](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-tilejson-metadata) and use this to add the source:

```
map.addSource({
  type: 'vector',
  url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{map_id}.json' // <-- tileJSON url
});
```

For your **source layer** question: Vector tiles include multiple "layers" of data/geometry, when adding a map layer you need to define which source-layer the map layer refers to. E.g. you can have a single vector tile set consisting of line strings and points (two different source-layers), but your map layer should only render on of them. You can either check to tile JSON to see what source-layers are included in your tile set or create a map style in mapbox studio, using your uploaded tile set as a source.

Comment: Yeah. The `mapbox://` URL is a shorthand for the last version, and isn't tied to a specific version of their API's URL structure.